# how to add route icon in notification android

Tags: android, icons, push-notification, routes

```
private void showNotification() {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.alert_light_frame,"Alarma!",System.currentTimeMillis());
  PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, People.CONTENT_URI), 0);
  notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Alarma!", nombre, myIntent);
  notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  notifyDetails.icon |= HEREEEEEEEEEEE
  mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID++, notifyDetails);
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Sucessfully Changed Time");

  }
```

in "HEReeeeeeeeeeeee" i need put a route, for example "/mnt/sdcard/Pou/4_1362782019815.png"

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) to build up your notifications as it makes things more convenient and additionally has a [setLargeIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) method that you can use to pass in any Bitmap you want (including one you load from the sdcard). There's also [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) in the support library if you need to target pre-Honeycomb

Answer (score 0):

1) Get icon bitmap from sdcard:

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/photo.jpg");
Bitmap notificationIconBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

2) Set bitmap for notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setLargeIcon(notificationIconBmp);       
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify("direct_tag", NOTIF_ALERTA_ID, builder.build());
```